# .NET core angular project cannot send data if the connection is not in the connected state?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I'm running a .NET core angular project in VScode on windows and I'm trying to get signalR to work but unfortunately things don't seem to be going my way.Before when I had my angular and .net core projects split up(web API and angular project separate) with the same code, this issue did not occur. It's when I switched to a .NET core angular project that it's now happening. Thanks in advance.

when I try to send a message to the server, I get the following error

[image]
ChatHub.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ProjectConker
{
    public class IMessage
    {
       public string timestamp;
       public string message;
       public string author;
       public string iconLink;
   }
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public Task SendToAll(string name, IMessage messageData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(messageData.message);
             return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", name, messageData);
        }
    } 
}
```

Angular Client component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ITag } from '../Tag/tag';
import { TagComponent } from '../Tag/tag.component';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { IMessage } from './Message';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, HttpTransportType } from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'chat',
  templateUrl: "./chatComponent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ['./chatComponent.component.css']
  // providers: [ ChatService ]
})

export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  hubConnection: HubConnection;

  messageData: IMessage;
  message: string;

  //profile info
  author: string;
  iconLink: string;

  messages: IMessage[] = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getRandomUser();

    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:5000/api/chat", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    }).build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));

    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (author: string, receivedMessage: IMessage) => {

      this.messages.push(receivedMessage);
    });

  }

  private getRandomUser() {
    this.http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          console.log(data);

          this.iconLink = data.results[0].picture.medium;
          this.author = data.results[0].name.first;

          console.log(this.iconLink);
        }
      );

  }

  public sendMessage(): void {

    var today = new Date();

    this.messageData = {
      author: this.author,
      message: this.message,
      timestamp: ("0" + today.getHours()).toString().slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + today.getMinutes()).toString().slice(-2),
      iconLink: this.iconLink
    };
    this.hubConnection
      .invoke('SendToAll', this.author, this.messageData)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

    this.message = '';
  }


}
```

angular client view

```
 <div class="outer-chat-container">
    <div class="chat-container">

        <ng-container *ngIf="messages.length > 0">
            <div class="message-box"  *ngFor="let message of messages">
              <img class="avatar" [src]='message.iconLink'>


              <div class="content">
                <div class="headline">
                    <p class="author">{{ message.author }}</p>
                    <div class="datetime">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                </div>


                <p class="message">{{ message.message }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

         </ng-container>
    </div>
    <form class="send-message-form" (ngSubmit)="sendMessage()" #chatForm="ngForm">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="message" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="Your message" required>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using ProjectConker.Models;
using ProjectConker.Roadmaps;
using ProjectConker.Searching;

namespace ProjectConker
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddHttpClient();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", 
            builder => 
            {
                builder.AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                       .WithOrigins("*")
                       .AllowCredentials();
            }));

            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

           // services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>();

            services.AddDbContext<ConkerDbContext>(
    options => options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll));

            services.AddScoped<SearchEngine>();
            services.AddTransient<RoadmapService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });

            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/chat");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
C:\Users\wasii\Documents\CodingProjects\ProjectConker\ClientApp>ng version
Your global Angular CLI version (8.3.5) is greater than your local
version (6.0.8). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.16.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/language-service         6.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

```
C:\Users\wasii\Documents\CodingProjects\ProjectConker>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.402
 Commit:    c7f2f96116

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.18362
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.402\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.7
  Commit:  b1e29ae826

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Where/when is `sendmessage` called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's review your `ChatComponent` Component, it initializes and tries to set up a connection to the Hub. Its `ngOnInit()` returns **immediately** after it binds an event handler for `ReceiveMessage`.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(...).build();
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', ...);
  }
```

Note it will take some time to connect to the Hub. If you try to send messages to the server **before the connection is set up**, it throws.

### How to fix:

Create a `thenable` to ensure the connection has been set up.

```
  private thenable: Promise<void>

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(...).build();
    this.start()
    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', ...);
  }

  private start() {
    this.thenable = this.hubConnection.start();
    this.thenable
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started!'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while establishing connection :('));
  }
```

Whenever you want to communicate with the Hub, invoke by `thenable` in promise-style. For example, your `sendMessage()` should be changed in the following way:

```
public sendMessage(): void {
    this.thenable.then(() =>{
        var today = new Date();
        this.messageData = ...
        this.hubConnection
           .invoke('SendToAll', this.author, this.messageData)
           .catch(err => console.error(err));
           this.message = '';
    });
}
```

---

**[Update]**

There're two other bugs in your code :

1. You registered the SignalR middleware after the Spa middleware. Be aware `UseSpa()` should be used as a catch-all middleware. You should invoke `UseSignalR()` before `UseSpa()`:

   ```
   app.UseSignalR(routes =>
   {
       routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/chat");
   });

   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
       ...
   });

   app.UseSpa(spa =>
   {
       ...
   });

   app.UseSignalR(routes =>                        
   {                                               
       routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/api/chat");  
   });
   ```
2. If you're connecting to the same server, avoid using hard-coded url:

   ```
   this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("http://localhost:5000/api/chat", {
         skipNegotiation: true,
         transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
       }).build();
   ```

   Otherwise, it fails when you're using a different port/protocol.

Comment: When I do so, the this.thenable.then() in sendMessage doesn't run and no errors show up.

Comment: @WasiimOuro This doesn't make sense. How do you know `this.thenable.then()` in sendMessage doesn't run?

Comment: @WasiimOuro Did you find any messages in your console that says `Connection started!` or `Error while establishing connection :(` ?

Comment: I found neither, just blank. Although SendMessage did get called.

Comment: @WasiimOuro Could you please put a `console.log(`executed!`)` in the `then((0=>{   ....  })` to see the output ? I'm asking this because it doesn't make sense if it is not executed.

Comment: the console.log does not run

Comment: Also, I find myself lacking in knowledge when it comes to .NET core internals. Any advice on that?

Comment: @WasiimOuro  Personally, I would suggest 1. Go through the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows) 2. Of course, the docs doesn't cover everything. Feel free to read the source code on GitHub and file a issue when there's a need (mainly [Asp.NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore) and [Common Extensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions))